# Is there any solution to take picture using laptop camera with Flutter desktop?

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, flutter-desktop

Is there any solution to take picture using the laptop camera with Flutter desktop (on Windows)?
I don't want to use go-flutter.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Any updates on this thread? Thanks.

Comment: I managed to open the camera referring to this Git repository, https://github.com/westracer/flutter_native_opencv, but the camera opens up in a new window, also not able to capture the image. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to [write a plugin](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/blob/master/plugins/README.md) that implements it using Windows APIs.

Since the Texture widget isn't supported for Windows yet, you would need to use a separate native window for any live preview UI.

Comment: did you have already write something like that ?
like an example on how to communicate between flutter desktop app and a native window.

Comment: The file_chooser plugin opens a separate window.

Answer (score 0):

use camera_windows 0.1.0+1, the official plugin